# Unable to access home folder in linux subsystem(WSL) from cmd

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Linux subsystem on Windows(not virtual machine).

I'm trying to enter the home folder `/mnt/c/Users/Gigg/AppData/Local/lxss/home`;
but, when I try to enter home from bash it tells me access denied.

If I run`ls -l` it tells me that I have no permission whatsoever for any of those folders,
but doing `chmod 755` on the folders doesn't change anything,
even if I use `sudo`.

How can I access my home folders?

Answer (score 0):

The files in ../AppData/Local/lxss/ are protected by microsoft (`hidden` and `system`).

**If you wish to corrupt Windows bash** you can do it by `unchecking` "`Hide protected operating system files (recommended)`" in the folder options window.

In this Microsoft blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

**Microsoft wrote:**

> **DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, create and/or modify Linux files**
>   **using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.**
>
> Also note: Opening files using some Windows tools may read-lock the
>   opened files and/or folders, preventing updates to file contents
>   and/or metadata, essentially resulting in corrupted files/folders.
>   Creating/changing Linux files from Windows will likely result in data
>   corruption and/or damage your Linux environment requiring you to
>   uninstall & reinstall your distro!
>
> Note: Your “Linux files” are any of the files and folders under
>   %localappdata%\lxss – which is where the Linux filesystem – distro and
>   your own files – are stored on your drive
>
> **Remember: There’s a reason we gave the %localappdata%\lxss\ folder ‘hidden’ & ‘system’ attributes**

Comment: Wait for `Creators' Update 2`. This issue will be resolved by Microsoft according to them.